# How to wire a class that impacts only sub-child of the first child in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using React (Next.js) and TailwindCSS.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h1 className="bg-red-400">first</h1>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1 className="bg-green-400">second</h1>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1 className="bg-green-400">third</h1>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1 className="bg-green-400">four</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to write TailwindCSS class that only change sub child background color of first child of `<ul>` like

```css
ul > li::first-child > h1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't target the `h1` with a default tailwind CSS class, but the first `li` can be targeted with [pseudo-class references](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first).

```html
<li className="first:bg-red-400 first:text-black">
```

[Tailwind recommends](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#avoiding-premature-abstraction) not doing this if possible, but you can also add your class that [reuses tailwind's styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply)

```css
@layer components {
 ul > li::first-child > h1 {
  @apply bg-red-400 text-black;
 }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the page you link to, I think you need to add the `first:` pseudo-class to the `<li>`, not the `<ul>`.